# Dropbox ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stone'

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Im trying to import Dropbox with the line:

```
import dropbox
```

on Google Colab but im getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-fac67f6fa745> in <module>()
     28 import math
     29 import io
---> 30 import dropbox
     31 from keras.models import Sequential
     32 from keras.layers import Dense

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/dropbox/auth.py in <module>()
      5 # pylint: skip-file
      6 from __future__ import unicode_literals
----> 7 from stone.backends.python_rsrc import stone_base as bb
      8 from stone.backends.python_rsrc import stone_validators as bv
      9 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stone'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It was working perfectly normal a day ago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a new release of Dropbox API was out today and it has that glitch. Just used the version before today by using

```
pip install dropbox==10.10.0
```

Comment: Yes, this is an issue in the dependency configuration of the latest release. We're fixing it up in the next release.

Comment: This is fixed now with v11.0.0.